# Cordova (Ionic) build issue (azure pipeline) on androidx.webkit.WebViewAssetLoader (missing?)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Building the cordova app locally works fine, however within the Azure pipeline I keep getting this error: (cordova-plugin-file)

```
/home/vsts/work/1/s/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/file/FileUtils.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.webkit.WebViewAssetLoader;
                      ^
  symbol:   class WebViewAssetLoader
  location: package androidx.webkit
/home/vsts/work/1/s/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/file/FileUtils.java:1268: error: package WebViewAssetLoader does not exist
        WebViewAssetLoader.PathHandler pathHandler = path -> {
                          ^
```

Any idea where to look for? All versions seem the same.

Cordova 11.0.0
Cordova-android 10.1.2
Ionic-cli 6.19.1

Thanks for any support